# How to move local git repo from Windows 7 to Mac OSX

Tags: git, macos, drupal

I have a drupal website running on my Windows 7 machine using WAMP, and want to migrate over to my Mac which uses MAMP. I have a dummy drupal site working on my MAC which was just for testing purposes.

Is it possible to move my local git repo from my windows machine in the WAMP folder on to a HDD, and then copy that into my MAMP htdocs folder?

Just saves doing a git clone, and setting everything up again in the settings.php file etc

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why didn't you simply try it before asking this question?

Comment: Setting everything up again? If you kept all your database settings then you don't have to update settings.php. But if something is different in your new environment then you have to update the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do it. You just have to copy the folder with `.git` hidden folder in it.

Comment: Thanks this worked. The reason I didn't try it before hand was because the website is quite large and required a long time to transfer over. But thanks guys - appreciate the help.

Comment: So , you always can upvote us. And Check an answer as right one , you know . Actually these gives us points. And This is one of the cause  we are helping each other. Smile.